# Getting unresolved identifier error while building firebase login

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting unresolved identifier error for the email and password variables. Here is the code for the view controller, I think it's an issue with the curly brackets and where they are placed but have messed with it for a little while and can't figure it out. I am trying to get it so when the user enters their email/password it sends the string to the database so they can use it to log in in the future.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var FirstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SignUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ErrorLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         setUpElements()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func setUpElements() {

        //Hide error label
        ErrorLabel.alpha = 0

        //Style the elements
        Utilities.styleTextField(FirstNameTextField)

        Utilities.styleTextField(LastNameTextField)

        Utilities.styleTextField(EmailTextField)

        Utilities.styleTextField(PasswordTextField)

        Utilities.styleFilledButton(SignUpButton)

    }

    func Validatefields () -> String? {
        //Check that all fields are filled in
        if FirstNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
           LastNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
           EmailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
           PasswordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {

            return "Please fill in all fields."
        }

        //Check if the password is secure
        let cleanedPassword = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanedPassword) == false {

            //password isn't secure enough
            return "Please make sure your password is at least 8 characters, contains a special character and a number."


        }

        return nil
    }

    @IBAction func SignUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Validate Fields
        let error = Validatefields()

        if error != nil {
            //something wrong with fields
           showError(error!)


        }


        else {

            //Create User
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                //Check for errors
                if err != nil {


                    //there was an error
                    self.showError("Error Creating User")

                }
                else {
                    // Create cleaned (No white spaces) version of data
                    let Firstname = FirstNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let LastName = LastNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let email2 = EmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let password2 = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)




                    //User was successfully created
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["Firstname":firstName,"LastName":lastName, "uid": result!.user.uid ])  {(error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            //Show error message
                            self.showError("User FirstName and Lastname couldn't be saved, You should still be able to log in.")

                        }




                    }
                    //Transition to home screen
                    func Transitiontohome () {


                let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as?
                    HomeViewController


                        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    }

            }






        }


    }



    }
    func showError (_ message:String) {
    ErrorLabel.text = message
    ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
}
}
```

Comment: If you can add the exact error you're getting, that will help too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm having a hard time finding out exactly where the error is. My first thought is `let db =` might not be right. I've included my code for you to try...

```
     // SIGN UP FUNCTION, first name, last name, email, password
let db = Database.database().reference()
func signUp(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (LocalUser?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let usersRef = db.child("users")
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {[weak self] (result, error) in

        if let uid = result?.user.uid {
            let newUser: [String: String] = ["firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "email": email]
            let newLocalUser = LocalUser(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email)
            usersRef.child(uid).setValue(newUser){(error: Error?, ref: DatabaseReference) in
                completion(newLocalUser, error)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

^^^ This code is in a Swift file called "Firebase Functions" — however, in the sign up screen itself "signupViewController" I have this code (I'm not seeing this in your code, and this is the feature that properly saves your data through the `acitivityIndicator`)

```
    // Create the user, process data and go to next View Controller
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    firebaseServer.signUp(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password) {[weak self] (user, error) in
        self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        if let user = user {
            newUser = user
        }



        if(error == nil) {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let signupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "introductionTextViewController")
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupVC, animated: true)

        } else {
            print("An error occured")
        }
    }
```

Does this all make sense?? My GitHub has all of this code, so feel free to take what might help! https://github.com/kcapretta/RadiusSocialNetworkingApp

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `email` with `self.EmailTextField.text` and `password` with `self.PasswordTextField.text`, so updated code

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.EmailTextField.text, password: self.PasswordTextField.text) { (result, err) in
```